# RPG language : How to make a loop?

Tags: rpg

I would like to learn the language RPG, How to make a loop for example?

Do know you a website that offers tutorials? I don't find nothing...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RPG is a proprietary language from IBM you will not find many tutorials online. Your best source for RPG is the IBM Knowledge Center, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/zzdow.htm . It comes with examples for such things as loops.

In RPG you have operation codes for such things as loops, short : opcodes. DOW = do while, DOU = do until, FOR. The aborting the iteration in a loop you have ITER and LEAVE.

And while you are just learning RPG you show starting learning free format RPG. Don't start with fixed format RPG. You can get into that later.

And if you are using pub400.com for learning RPG you can also use the free version of MiWorkplace (at miworkplace.com) for a nice and free editor. You don't have to use SEU.

Comment: Sorry for the desagrement, but I need you, I tried to install the server via pub400 but I am stuck. You can help here, when you have the time please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65244121/how-to-install-server-pub400-on-miworkplace

Answer (score 0):

There is a little RPG tutorial here, although it doesn't have anything about loops. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1108749