# How to install server Pub400 on MiWorkplace?

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I would like to learn the RPG language, I am registered on pub400.com and I downloaded MiWorkplace IDE.

I have to create a new connection but I don't understand how to install the server.

In the first step:

[image]

In the Connection field: I indicate `Pub400.com`?

Server field: I indicate `PUB400`?

User field: `nek` it's my username from pub400

My information is correct?

[image]

In this step, I don't know what is the library to add ???

[image]

Also after the step next

[image]

I thank you for your time and your explanations.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection is just the name of your connection. You can enter there what you want ... preferably something meaningful like pub400. This name will be displayed in the Remote Explorer.

Server is the hostname of the server ... in your case pub400.com .

User is your username on the remote system.

The User Guide is a good place to start: https://miworkplace.com/docs/

HTH

Comment: thank you a lot for your help. My problem is solved. Tank you very much for IDE. :-)